# Is it possible to remove a character from the middle of the output line without removing the characters after it?

Tags: c

I did a little code example to show you what I want to do:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <term.h>

int ft_putchar(int ch)
{
    char c = (char)ch;
    return (write(1, &c, 1));
}

int main(void)
{
    tgetent(getenv("SHELL"), NULL);
    char * le = tgetstr("le", NULL); // get the termcap for cursor left

    write(1, "Hello world!", 12);
    tputs(le, 1, &ft_putchar); // move the cursor to the left
    write(1, "\b", 1); // erase character
    return (0);
}
```

So: as you can see I'm writing "Hello World!" and then what I want to do is erase for this example the 'd' without removing the '!', the problem is that when I move the cursor to the left then print '\b', it removes the current character but also all characters after it, so the final output is `Hello worl` instead of `Hello worl!`, so my question is: Can I avoid that to happen or do I need to rewrite the end everytime after erasing a character in the middle?
(PS: I know the `tgetent` function is not protected but it's just for the example)

Comment: `\b` doesn't delete anything, it just moves the cursor back. You can overwrite a character with a space to delete it, but this won't move the following characters back.

Comment: See: `tput cub1` (moves characters left by 1) and `tput cub N` (where `N` is the number of characters to move left)

Comment: I think you meant `tgetent(getenv("TERM"), NULL);`